# Add column in database from controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add a column in a mysql table from a controller. The user completes a form, and when he sends it, it creates a new column (not row) with the information in the form. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you added your column as strong parameter in you controller?

Comment: @RichPeck Why ?
@ MuhamadAkbarBinWidayat No.

Comment: Writing an answer to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it create new column

**Don't**.

Your database is sacrosanct, *dynamically* altering it is like dynamically changing a car based on some user's request. A car has four wheels, engine and seats. You can *change* the colour, tyres, etc... but not the fundamentals.

It's the same with web apps - you should not be changing the fundamental structure of your system. Sure, you'll be able to change various aspects of it (User Avatar etc), but the underlying basis of the system (the `db` schema) should be kept above any changes.

---

What you *should* be doing is maintaining your database fidelity through a tight set of `Models`, allowing you to create a dynamic experience *around* the data you've been provided.

For example...

> The user complete a form and when he send it, it create new column

A *better* way to explain this will be to use a [`user story`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story).

I'll surmise the following in your case:

> A user wants to add a new project to his portfolio. He fills out the form to explain what the project will be and adds a number of extra fields specific for that project.

I think you're asking about the "extra fields" part...

You have to remember Rails is built on top of a *relational database*:

[image]

This means that you have the flexibility provided by your *models* to grant your users the capacity to *add* and *manipulate* as many pieces of associated data as they need.

The data they add to the system can have *any* name & *any* structure, so long as you provide that functionality within the system itself...

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects
   has_many :specialized_fields, through: :projects
end 

#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :specialized_field
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :specialized_field
end

#app/models/specialized_field.rb
class SpecializedField < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects
   has_many :users, through: :projects
end
```

According to my example above,

- `User` can make a `Project`
- `Project` can have `specialized fields` (above the standard fields)
- `User` can add specialized fields to the model

Thus you can do the following:

```
#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @project = current_user.projects.new #-> assuming you're using Devise
      @specialized_field = @project.build_specialized_field
   end

   def create
      @project = Project.save project_params
      @project.save
   end

   private

   def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :start_time, :end_time, specialized_field_attributes: [:name, :value])
   end
end
```

The form could be as follows:

```
#app/views/projects/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.fields_for :specialized_field do |s| %>
      <%= s.text_field :name %>
      <%= s.text_field :value %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to add new columns to the database via the controller? This shouldn't be the case - and in general I couldnt' think of a single reason why this should ever be required. It sounds unconventional and against design principles.

If you add more information of what is required and what you are tyring to do I am pretty sure we can work out an alternative solution. (I bet what you are trying to do can be achieved with a many-to-many relationship, or similar, somehow). Post more information and see what we can do.

But as answer and solution I'd say it shouldn't be required.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? Database design is part of the application development, so *you* are the one deciding the rows. When the user inputs data, there are a gazillion things that can go wrong (hacks, invalid values...), which can affect your entire database. It's not worth risking that.

If you want a flexible schema, you can store hashes in a specific field. 
For example you have a `extra_data` field which is a hash. Then in your form you can have to inputs, `input_name` and `input_value` which will go to the hash. This way you will have more flexible values for the same column and you don't need to change your database schema.